# Force CSS Style

Tags: html, css

I have a wordpress theme which have its default styling, I developed a new page template and wrote some styles specifically for it but for some reason the styles aren't being applied.

The styles include table cell-padding.

When inspecting the code, the css I applied is being stroked out. How can I force that CSS to apply itself. I have already tried using the `!important` but still no success

Answer (score 0):

usually if you are developing your own theme for wordpress that there are no problems with the application of styles possible presence of an error in the connection of style, even when finished remaking theme personally I have no problems

Answer (score 0):

Can you make sure your own CSS code is called after the main CSS code ?
Maybe by changing the order of CSS calls in your head section like this :

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="defaultWordpress.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="myOwn.css">
</head>
```

*edit : default Wordpress css first* :-)

Comment: yes it is possible that the error in order Connecting styles

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you have to use all classes and ids of div to declare style for it. Anyway you shouldn't use `!important`, but try to describe your div precisely.

Answer (score 0):

**Write CSS (stylesheet) at the end of the all css files in header, Write css in Hierarchy level. select parent class or id and written down css**

**CSS Declaration in Header**

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="defaultwordpress.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="own.css">
</head>
```

Comment: I am writing the styles enclosed in a style tags in the php page template itself. That means that the styles are loaded after the header.php

Comment: Can you paste link, so I can check what exactly is the issue.

Comment: Hi I checked your site, in general for Wordpress if you have installed any theme from wordpress theme directory and want to overwrite theme css, best practice is to create a child theme and overwrite the parents theme css (https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes). If you are directly editing the installed theme the above approach should work, by including your css after the css of the theme.